# "classes.jar" doesn't exist - Android Support Design

Tags: android, xamarin, android-support-library

I was getting a bunch of errors when I updated the Android Design Support library to v.23.4.0. I resolved them by copying m2repository_r32 inside the content folder inside all the package folders of the library which resolved all the errors expect one.
I'm still getting:

```
Error 7 Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.4.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.   Yourtime
```

which doesn't make sense as the file "classes.jar" does exist in the "embedded" folder of "Android.Support.Vector.Drawable".
I really don't know how to resolve this. I've been trying for hours without any luck. Please help!

Comment: `23.4.0.0` doesn't look right - should be `23.4.0`

Comment: @ianhanniballake that folder was automatically created with the update

Comment: My guide on this general topic might help: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/f6291eacd4da5f6aa4cd

Comment: @JonDouglas I was able to fix the issue by removing the dll and adding it back again for that particular reference. Don't know why it worked but it did. I will have a look at your guide. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Clearing local cache for the package should resolve this issue. In your case, please

1. Goto C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Xamarin
2. Delete folder named "Android.Support.Vector.Drawable"
3. Build Solution/Project